# Query Mongodb Sum of firsts element of an array of objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I would like to write a query for summing each field `payment` of the first object inside an array, for each element of my database.

The schema is the following:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    plate : String,
    category : String,
    brand : String,
    model : String,
    sign : String,

    tax : [{
        date : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        payment : { type: Number, default: 0 },
    }],


});
```

I wrote the following function for my query:

```
function(callback){     
        Machine.aggregate(
            [
                {$unwind: "$tax"},
                {$group : {
                    _id : null ,
                    tot : { $sum: "$tax.payment"}
                }}
            ]
        ,callback);
    }
```

But in this way I retrieve the sum of all the payments inside the array tax. My goal is to take only the first, so I tried with `$tax.0.payment` and using `arrayElemAt : [$tax,0]` but all my trials gave a tot = 0.

Comment: `arrayElemAt` was one correct approach to solve this. ve' posted an answer based on that.. check if that's what solves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is pick out the first element of each of `payment` array field via [**`$arrayElemAt`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) with projection and then group-sum the field [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/).

**Query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      firstPayment: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$tax",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      PaymentSum: {
        $sum: "$firstPayment.payment"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Demo O/P:**

```
[
  {
    "PaymentSum": 11,
    "_id": null
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Machine.aggregate({$unwind: 
        {path: "$tax"}
    },
    {$group:{
         _id: "$_id",
         payment: {$first: "$tax.payment"}
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: null,
        total: {$sum: "$payment"}
    }}
)
```

**Explanation:**

First I used **`$unwind`** on tax, then in the first **`$group stage`** I grouped them according to **_id**,

that way I will get the first payment information from unwinded tax array.

Then I used $sum to add them in the second **`$group stage`**.

> I tested with this data:

**Machine** collection docs:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dbf09a4d7912bcbc61ee9e4"),
    "tax" : [
        {
            "payment" : 10
        },
        {
            "payment" : 20
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dbf09aad7912bcbc61ee9e5"),
    "tax" : [
        {
            "payment" : 30
        },
        {
            "payment" : 40
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dbf09afd7912bcbc61ee9e6"),
    "tax" : [
        {
            "payment" : 50
        },
        {
            "payment" : 60
        }
    ]
}
```

The **result** I got is:

```
{ "_id" : null, "tot" : 90 }
```

I hope this fulfills your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Add $arrayElemAt in your aggregate like this..

```
Machine.aggregate(
        [
            {$unwind: "$tax"},
            {$group : {
                _id : null ,
                tot : { $sum:  { $arrayElemAt : [ "$tax.payment", 0  ]}
            }}
        ]
    ,callback);
```

Comment: This would lead to a wrong result, mostly the `tot` will be 0. Since `tax.payment` is not an array to work with in the first place (according to OP).